# Can anyone explain this interesting C# problem?

Tags: c#

I hit a bizarre problem earlier which I have replicated in a new console application. I wonder, can anyone explain why this occurs?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoSomething(0);

        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void DoSomething(int? value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do Something int? called");
    }

    public static void DoSomething(MyEnum value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do Something MyEnum called");
    }

    public static enum MyEnum : int
    {
        test

    }
}
```

You get an error on the DoSomething line:

> Error 1   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'DoSomething(int?)' and 'DoSomething(MyEnum)'

However if you change the zero to any other number, there is no such problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The C# language specification states that there is an implicit conversion from the integer literal `0` to any enum type:

> ### 13.1.3 Implicit enumeration conversions
>
> An implicit enumeration conversion permits the decimal-integer-literal 0 to be converted to any enum-type.

Therefore, any other integer literal can only convert to `int?` and is thus unambiguous; but the literal `0` is convertible to both `int?` and your enum.

It doesn’t matter which values are defined in your enum. Even if you have an enum like `enum Test { Cats=7 }`, the above still applies. Remember that all enums can have all values of their underlying integer types and are not restricted to the values actually declared.

Comment: That's interesting, what happens if you have an enum of { Cats=7 } and you cast zero into it, what do you get then?

Comment: @SLC: The value 0, of course. Similarly, if you cast 47 into it, you get the value 47, typed as the enum type. Like I said, enum types are not restricted to the values declared. You can cast any integer of any integer type to any enum type whose underlying integer type is the same.

Answer (score 8):

This is because the literal `0` is implicitly convertible to any `enum`.

So in the first situation, the `0` is "equally" convertible to either `int?` or `MyEnum`. Neither conversion is "better" than the other so the compiler doesn't know which method you're expecting to call.

If you change the `0` to a `1` then it works because `1` is *not* implicitly convertible to `MyEnum`, so the only matching method is the one that takes an `int?` argument.

Comment: What if you have an enum like `enum Test { Cats=7 }` ?

Comment: This doesn't explain why the code works if you don't use a nullable integer: `DoSomething(int value)`?

Comment: @Darin: The OP didn't ask that, but if you use `int` rather than `int?` then no conversion is required for that method, so it's a better match.

Comment: @SLC: It doesn't matter what values you use, the literal `0` is implicitly convertible to any `enum`. (And any non-zero integer can be explicitly cast to any `enum`, assuming that the range of the underlying type can accomodate it.)

Answer (score 0):

An implicit enumeration conversion permits the decimal-integer-literal 0 to be converted to any enum-type.